# Missing permission to execute the native method: filesystem.readFile

Tags: neutralinojs

I'm new in NeutralinoJS, I'm trying my first app and I need to read the content of a json file. I'm trying by using `Neutralino.filesystem.readFile` method, but it fails with error

```json
{
  code: "NE_RT_NATPRME",
  message: "Missing permission to execute the native method: filesystem.readFile"
}
```

I've tried also by reading the status of the file with `filesystem.getStats` but it fails with the same error. How can I activate the permissions to run `filesystem.readFile` and other `filestystem` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was actually just coming across this same problem. Make sure in your `neutralino.config.json` you have `filesystem.*` in your `nativeAllowList` section like so:

```json
  "nativeAllowList": [
    "app.*",
    "os.*",
    "filesystem.*",
    "debug.log"
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and welcome in stackoverflow, it's strange it's not in in official documentation for `neutralino.filesystem` https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/filesystem/

Comment: I agree, the documentation is actually missing a lot lol, hopefully it continues to get updated because I have come across some problems with obvious solution in hindsight that are just nit mentioned.

Comment: Not actually working...